# Best way to display a wrapped list in Android?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-listview

What's the best way to display items in a list such that they are visually ordered like the following?:

```
_________________  _________________
|                | |                |
|       1        | |       2        |
|________________| |________________|
_________________  _________________
|                | |                |
|       3        | |       4        |
|________________| |________________|
_________________  _________________
|                | |                |
|       5        | |       6        |
|________________| |________________|
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a grid layout manager to do it. Set this as layout manager of your recycler view

new GridLayoutManager(context, NUMBER_OF_COLUMN)